# Want to skip last and first 5 lines while reading file in python

Tags: python, file, file-read

If I want to see only data between line number 5 to what comes before last 5 rows in a file. While I was reading that particular file.

Code I have used as of now :

```
f = open("/home/auto/user/ip_file.txt")
lines = f.readlines()[5:] # this will start from line 5 but how to set end
for line in lines:
        print("print line ", line )
```

Please suggest me I am newbie for python.
Any suggestions are most welcome too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a neat feature of slicing, you can count from the end with negative slice index, ([see also this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/explain-pythons-slice-notation)):

```
lines = f.readlines()[5:-5]
```

just make sure there are more than 10 lines:

```
all_lines = f.readlines()
lines = [] if len(all_lines) <= 10 else all_lines[5:-5]
```

(this is called a *ternary operator*)